# How to access databases if admin db dropped?

Tags: mongodb

While using mongodb I accidentally dropped 'admin' db. Now I cannot access any of the database.

```
replicaSet1:PRIMARY> db.auth("root","root")
1
replicaSet1:PRIMARY> db.dropDatabase()
{ "dropped" : "admin", "ok" : 1 }
replicaSet1:PRIMARY> db.auth("root","root")
Error: Authentication failed.
0
```

Comment: put the error to the question, not the script how to drop it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps to restore admin database and access to other database using admin user:

(1) Connect local database with system user using keyfile.

> mongo -u __system -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)"
>   --authenticationDatabase local

note: path-to-keyfile = this is your key-file path of mongo.

(2) Switch to admin database.

> use admin

(3) Create Admin user with 'dbOwner, readWrite and readAnyDatabase' roles.

> db.createUser({user: "admin", pwd: "cal@cas", roles: [{ role:
>   "dbOwner", db: "admin" },{ role: "readWrite", db: "admin" },{ role:
>   "readAnyDatabase", db: "admin" }]});

(4) View database list using below command.

> show dbs;

Answer (score 1):

Deleting **admin** db means loosing access to all the databases.

Enable localhost authentication bypass(if not enabled) and restart mongod. Now create the users again.

Comment: Good solution, however, I'd like to add that even after dropping the 'admin' db, other databases (if exist) that contain users with appropriate access levels, can be used to login (to the corresponding database).